# WINE Not visible, yet when I try to install it says already installed

Tags: wine

Ubuntu 17.10

I am not able to launch WINE to install Windows programs. When I do try to install WINE it says already installed.

Comment: How are you trying to run wine? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: There are no error messages. When I go to look for wine in my installed programs I get WINETRICKS but no WINE. When I go to software download and type in WINE it says already installed. Same for VLC Media Player. Odd for sure.

Comment: @vidarlo: Seeing the response, that is not a comments but an answer.  If you convert that to an answer and ping me, I'll come back and upvote...

Comment: @NickAnthony As you've never accepted an answer here on the site: if an answer helps you and works, **don't forget to click the grey check-mark** next to it turning it into a beautiful green and advertising to other users that *yes, this answer worked!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to run winetricks.

It will allow you to start and install Windows Software.

Once you've installed Windows software using winetricks, the installed software should turn up in the application menus automatically.

Winetricks can in addition be used to configure various aspects of wine.

To run winetricks interactively from a terminal use:

```
winetricks --gui
```